# How can I make a multi column list view which is horizontally scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I am trying to implement something like this where the list view has sectioned headers and can be scrolled horizontally across multiple columns. What is the best way to implement this. Is ListView even the right way to implement this?

[image]

Comment: Look into GridView instead of a ListView.

Comment: GridView isnt horizontally scrollable right?

Comment: yes it is, it has methods where you can scroll to a specific position smoothScrollToPosition (int position), also you can specify both vertical and horizontal scroll bars

Comment: Instead of multiple columns which sounds very much like Excel spreadsheet and it gets too complicated, how about multiple tabs or NavigationDrawer? You still will use ListView.